# Mouse event on tkinter python, didn't return an output

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

i'm currently using Visual Studio Code to learn how to use tkinter, i did find some tutorials on youtube to create a mouse event function [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkCbinbgbdw&index=7&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBwibXFtPtflztSNPGuIB_d). i'm completely a newbie in programming.

here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def leftClick(event):
    print("left")

def middleClick(event):
    print("middle")

def rightClick(event):
    print("right")

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=250)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)
frame.bind("<Button-2>", middleClick)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", rightClick)

root.mainloop()
```

i don't know why there's no output when i click somewhere inside the frame. when i click left right or middle button on mouse should return "left" "right" "middle" in output window, i did check the terminal window too and nothing was returned there. check the youtube link above for my reference of what i am doing.

here's the terminal output:

> PS C:\Users\abdull\Documents!! Code\single file> cd 'c:\Users\abdull\Documents!! Code\single file'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\abdull\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\Users\abdull.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py' '59359' 'c:\Users\abdull\Documents!! Code\single file\gtktest.py'

ps: sorry for my bad grammar, (2nd language)

Operating system : Windows 10
mouse = logitech m331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your frame is not getting placed/rendered in the ui. You need to call the [`pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#the-packer) method on it:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def leftClick(event):
    print("left")

def middleClick(event):
    print("middle")

def rightClick(event):
    print("right")

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=250)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)
frame.bind("<Button-2>", middleClick)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", rightClick)
frame.pack() # <---------

root.mainloop()
```